# Jquery - Jerky animation

Tags: jquery, animation, timer

I have a little animation that's running a bit jerky in all browsers.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/iltdev/nN6cT/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you are doing wrong, is that you are firing new animations before the previous ones have finished for an element..

That is because you are using the timing plugin and firing the new animation on fixed intervals. Better to use the callback argument of the `.animation()` method and start a new animation after the previous has completed..

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qaGyS/2/

---

Another thing, is that you are animating a very small distance over a long time (for that distance). For example you animating 10 pixels over a second .. this is slow and you can see the individual movements..

with faster animations at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qaGyS/1/

Comment: Thanks, Gaby.  That has definately smoothed things for me.  I think my computer is partly to blame as I've tried on a couple of colleague's PC's and its a bit smoother again.  The idea of the animation is to eventually have people bobbing up and down on balloons, hence the small amount of movement over a long period of time.  Thanks again for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using easing for your animations. For example: http://matthewlein.com/experiments/easing.html

Comment: I thought easing just changed the timings e.g. to give a slowing down effect? On my computer the whole animation seems to get 'stuck' for a second or two, then start moving again... almost as if the computer is struggling to keep up.